# What is the truth table for a logic NOT gate with two inversion bubbles?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, not-gate

I am currently reversw engineering a PCB and it contains a D-type register chip. The chips internal circuit diagram shows a NOT gate with two bubbles on it both in the front and the back. My question is if this is the same as a buffer or if this case some other meaning? And it would be great if a truth table could be included in the answer.

Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls090/sdls090.pdf

Comment: Truth table is in the datasheet.

Comment: You might want to check this answer as well: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/452460 since it explains the intention behind using the circle before the triangle and therefore also the circle after the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as a buffer. The bubble at the input is used to indicate that this input is active low. It drives the input of the reset, which also has a bubble at the input and is therefore also active low.